# add class to li when a tag inside is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to add a class to the li when the  tag is clicked i am using jQuery addclass but not sure how to get it to the LI

```
<ul class="nav">
 <li class=""> <!---------add class to here---->
   <a href="default.asp">Home</a> <!-------- when this is clicked---->
   <ul>
       <li><a href="news.asp">link 1</a></li><!-------- but NOT when this is clicked----->
       <li><a href="news.asp">link 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="news.asp">link 3</a></li>
   <ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
 <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
 <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

I hope this makes sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: *Ninja answers*. In complement, here is the doc about this `parent()` selector. https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Did you want the nested links to add the class to their immediate LI too?  That changes the answer.

Comment: HTML error, the last `<ul>` should be `</ul>` for the inner list.

Comment: Added version for you that turns off the matching classes as requested in comment, but everyone is too busy on the early answers to notice :)

Comment: top work:-) thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For efficiency, you should use a single delegated event handler attached to your `.nav` element:

If you want all the sibling element to remove that class use `not`.

e.g.

```
    $('.nav').on('click', 'li > a', function(){
          var $li = $(this).parent();
          $li.siblings().not($li.addClass('smclass')).removeClass('smclass');
    });
```

Note: Answers with `.nav > li` (emphasis on `>`) will only work for the top level links. You need to clarify if you want the same behaviour on all links (which this example currently does).

If you only wanted it to work on the top-level links it would be

```
    $('.nav').on('click', '> li > a', function(){
          var $li = $(this).parent();
          $li.siblings().not($li.addClass('smclass')).removeClass('smclass');
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve by adding following click function

```
$("ul.nav > li > a").click(function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass("your_class");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use immediate child selector to target all direct child elements:

```
$('.nav > li > a').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().addClass('smclass')
});
```

Comment: The question is ambiguous on how nested links should behave. You need to include your first answer too (just in case) :)

Comment: Brillant thanks so much, this works, but how do i make it remove the class if the class has been added to another li?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: great...you got it :)